Error using cv.glmertee(): family$family : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
I am currently using R to run a generalized linear mixed model tree using glmertree. Bare with me as I am limited in my R programming experience.
I am able to run the model without errors. However, when I use cv.glmertree to obtain standard errors and valid inferences, I get this error:
Error in family$family : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
I'm using the guideline from: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmertree/glmertree.pdf - I am trying to troubleshoot, but I'm not seeing what the problem is.
Here is my code:
train <- sample(1:nrow(non_miss), size =2382 , replace = TRUE)
test <- sample(1:nrow(non_miss), size =2382 , replace = TRUE)

tree1 <-glmertree(event ~ 1 | (1| cohort) |   ageatenroll + hiv + racecat  + visitsite 
                  + edu + smkgrp_hist + percent_drug + comorbid_hist + percent_depress, 
                 data=non_miss[train, ], 
                 family=binomial, 
                 nAGQ = 0,
                 minsize=200)

tree2 <- cv.glmertree(tree1, newdata=non_miss[test, ], reference=13)`

When I run the last line, I get the following:
> tree2 <- cv.glmertree(tree1, newdata=non_miss[test, ], reference=13)
Error in family$family : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
> traceback()
6: family$family %in% c("quasibinomial", "quasipoisson", "quasi")
5: lme4::glFormula(formula = ff, data = newdata, family = family, 
   control = glmer.control, nAGQ = nAGQ)
4: eval(mc, parent.frame(1L))
3: eval(mc, parent.frame(1L))
2: glmer(ff, data = newdata, nAGQ = nAGQ, family = family, control = glmer.control)
1: cv.glmertree(tree1, newdata = non_miss[test, ], reference = 13)

Any assistance or directions is be greatly appreciated!
